# Debian's zic missing -b option

Tags: docker, timezone, debian

I'm interested in using `zic`'s `-b` option on `debian:buster-slim` image. Although I see `-b` being listed on the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/manpages/zic.8.en.html), it errors out when I run it locally:

```
> docker run -it debian:buster-slim bash
root@60a90ca657de:/# zic --version
zic (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28
root@60a90ca657de:/# zic -b
zic: invalid option -- 'b'
zic: usage is zic [ --version ] [ --help ] [ -v ] \
        [ -l localtime ] [ -p posixrules ] [ -d directory ] \
        [ -L leapseconds ] [ filename ... ]

Report bugs to <http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

How can I use the -b option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-b` flag to `zic` was [added](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=61d64408a1f42b0340d37ea0c90a9f028ffb1bfd) to glibc in version 2.32.  Debian Buster has glibc 2.28.  Even Debian unstable has only version 2.31 right now, [according to the Debian Package Tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc).

You can see on [Repology](https://repology.org/project/glibc/versions) which distros currently have glibc 2.32.  The list includes Ubuntu Groovy.  If it's an option in your case, you could use `ubuntu:groovy` instead of `debian:buster-slim`.

You may be wondering why `-b` shows up in the Debian man page you linked to.  You linked to the man page in Debian Unstable (not Buster).  If you select the Buster version instead, it doesn't list the `-b` option.  Additionally, in Debian, the man page for `zic` comes from the `manpages` package, not the `glibc` package, so it's possible for the man page and the binary to be out of sync, and it looks like that's the case right now.

Comment: ah I was looking so hard for a changelog, but that commit is even better. Thanks!